# Continue SSH background task/jobs when closing SSH or when Shell is disconnected

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line, bash, ssh

I am running an MPI program with SSH secure shell. Due to Wi-Fi disconnection, my la[top looses connection with server and causes failure of running process at server.

As per above suggested solutions, I tried to use "screen -dmSL" command with defining the "workstuff" named with another name and then the command (which is in the form - "./mpirun ......") that I have given to execute the process.

In terminal (in OpenSuse Linux environment) the process I have suspended with "Ctrl-z". It worked well. But when I restarted the SSH Shell after an hour to check either the process completed or not and entered the command "screen -x "...." (workstuff name). I got message as "There is no screen to be attached matching "..." (workstuff name).

I executed the process after entering to sub-folders. So I tried in that way too. But nothing happened.

Was I missed something while giving the command? Plz provide the solution.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to see the screen output?  If not, simply run the process with an ampersand (&) at the end like so:

```
./my_process&
```

If you *do* need the output, then in most cases you can pipe stdout to a file like this:

```
./my_process > output.txt&
```

Comment: Hi. The suggested solutions worked. The only thing I won't understand that while returning back to check the ongoing process, the same command should be given again or the server works just on previously defined condition i.e. "./my_process.... ". And further if I want just close the SSH shell not the process, then does it need any another command?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

> nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &

Comment: I am not sure about nohup. But I have checked the previous comments related to "nohup". At there the most sophisticated solution I found was "screen". 

So, do u mean the "nohup" will be a better option for particular my problem or it is a common solution for all similar questions?
Also it is not clear from above solution that how could I come out of SSH shell (by any further command or just quitting the SSH) and how to return back to process.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the -r/-R and -d/-D options on the man page for `screen` .  Running `screen -D -RR -x ... (workstuff)` works for me when a detached screen is not letting me reattach.